# R summing certain columns in each row

Tags: r, matrix, sum, aggregate

I'm having an issue, but I'm sure it's super easy for someone who is very familiar with R. 
I have a matrix that is 3008 x 3008. What I want is it to sum every 8 columns in each row. So essentially you'd end up with a new matrix that is now 367 x 367.

Here's a small example:

```
           C.1 C.2 C.3 C.4 C.5 C.6
    row1    1   2   1   2   5   6
    row1    1   2   3   4   5   6
    row1    2   6   3   4   5   6
    row1    1   2   3   4   10   6
```

So say I wanted to sum these for every 3 columns in each row, I'd want to end up with:

```
           C.1 C.2
    row1    4   13
    row1    6   15
    row1   11   15
    row1    6   20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# m is your matrix
n <- 8
grp <- seq(1, ncol(m), by=n)
sapply(grp, function(x) rowSums(m[, x:(x+n-1)]))
```

Some explanation if you're new to R. `grp` is a sequence of numbers that gives the starting points for each group of columns: 1, 9, 17, etc if you want to sum every 8 columns.

The `sapply` call can be understood as follows. For each number in `grp`, it calls the `rowSums` function, passing it those matrix columns corresponding to that group number. Thus when `grp` is 1, it gets the row sums for columns 1-8; when `grp` is 9, it gets the row sums for columns 9-16 and so on. These are vectors, which `sapply` then binds together into a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Transform your matrix to an array, then use `apply` and `rowSums`.

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), 
                 .Dim = c(4L, 6L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.4", "C.5", "C.6")))

n <- 3 #this needs to be a factor of the number of columns
a <- array(mat,dim=c(nrow(mat),n,ncol(mat)/n))
apply(a,3,rowSums)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4   13
# [2,]    6   15
# [3,]   11   15
# [4,]    6   20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create sample data:
df <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)

#Choose the number of columns you'd like to sum up (e.g., 3 or 8)
number_of_columns_to_sum <- 3

df2 <- NULL #Set to null so that you can use cbind on the first value below
for (i in seq(1,ncol(df), by = number_of_columns_to_sum)) {
  df2 <- cbind(df2, rowSums(df[,i:(i+number_of_columns_to_sum-1)]))
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `cbind` within a loop (very slow), and no need to use `for` here (side effect).

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Though it may not be as elegant

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), 
                 .Dim = c(4L, 6L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(c("row1", "row1", "row1", "row1"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.4", "C.5", "C.6")))

new<- data.frame((mat[,1]+mat[,2]+mat[,3]),(mat[,4]+mat[,5]+mat[,6]))
names(new)<- c("C.1","C.2")
new
```

Comment: Pretty useless with a 3008 x 3008 matrix, isn't it?